# Undefined reference when defining a template function in the global namespace which is declared in an inline anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Given:

```
namespace ns
{
  inline namespace
  {
    template<typename T>
    void f();
  }
}

template<typename T>
void ns::f() {}

int main()
{
    ns::f<int>();
}
```

GCC (trunk) complains that `ns::f<int>` is not defined. Clang (trunk) is fine with this. See: https://godbolt.org/z/n5qMs85q5

Is this a known bug in GCC? Is Clang incorrect?

Comment: My workaround for this is:

    namespace {
      inline namespace local {
        using namespace ns;

        template<typename T>
        void f();
      }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void local::f() {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is right, the program is ill-formed.

What can be done with members of an `inline` namespace is specified in [[namespace.def]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.def#7):

> Members of an inline namespace can be used in most respects as though they were members of the enclosing namespace. Specifically, the inline namespace and its enclosing namespace are both added to the set of associated namespaces used in [argument-dependent lookup](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep) whenever one of them is, and a [*using-directive*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#nt:using-directive) that names the inline namespace is implicitly inserted into the enclosing namespace as for an [unnamed namespace](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.unnamed). Furthermore, each member of the inline namespace can subsequently be [partially specialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec), [explicitly instantiated](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.explicit), or [explicitly specialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec) as though it were a member of the enclosing namespace. Finally, looking up a name in the enclosing namespace via explicit qualification ([[namespace.qual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.qual)) will include members of the inline namespace brought in by the [*using-directive*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#nt:using-directive) even if there are declarations of that name in the enclosing namespace.

So, an `inline` namespace member can be looked up and even *specialized* using it's enclosing scope name, but not *defined*.

To define a member, you still need to fully qualify it. But you can't qualify an unnamed namespace.

To fix it, just give it some name:

```
namespace ns
{
  inline namespace X
  {
    template<typename T>
    void f();
  }
}

template<typename T>
void ns::X::f()
{
  T t{};
  ++t;
}
```

---

Bonus info:

To understand how unnamed namespaces work, see [[namespace.unnamed]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.def#namespace.unnamed-1):

> An *unnamed-namespace-definition* behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> inline(opt) namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
> using namespace unique ;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```

So an unnamed namespace does actually have a name, it's just hidden from the user. Hence it can never be fully qualified to define stuff in it (which is actually the point).

And [[namespace.memdef]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.def#namespace.memdef-2):

> Members of a **named namespace** can also be defined **outside** that namespace by explicit qualification ...

Which basically means *if you can qualify it, you can define it*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have added this to the original question, but in case `f` is not a template function, GCC is happy to compile the code, see for example: https://godbolt.org/z/sab7TTEYr.

So in that particular case, GCC would be wrong then if I understand you correctly?

Comment: In C++, if something compiles, it doesn't necessarily mean it's correct. Notice that the error comes from the linker. I guess in case of a regular function GCC produces the same mangled name, which ends up linking correctly. But give this some time, maybe someone else will post another answer.